# How to specify validation group for @Valid?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, controller

I get so parameters in @Controller @RequestMapping method:

```
@ModelAttribute("myCandidate") @Valid Candidate myCandidate,
BindingResult result
```

How can I explicit specify validation group for myCandidate ?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

The standard java `@Valid` annotation doesn't support groups.  However, Spring now includes an `@Validated` annotation which does the same job as `@Valid`, but allows you to specify which groups to use in the validation:

```
@ModelAttribute("myCandidate") @Validated(UpdateGroup.class) Candidate myCandidate
```

Note that this annotation is only available in Spring 3.1 and newer.

Comment: Note that `@Validated` is not applicable to fields

Comment: When I use `@Validated`, annotations like `@Pattern` are ignored which get validated with `@Valid`. They do appearently not behave the same when used from a REST controller.