# Difference between @Valid and @Validated in Spring

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-mvc

Spring supports two different validation methods: Spring validation and JSR-303 bean validation. Both can be used by defining a Spring validator that delegates to other delegators including the bean validator. So far so good.

But when annotating methods to actually request validation, it's another story. I can annotate like this

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/object", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody TestObject create(@Valid @RequestBody TestObject obj, BindingResult result) {
```

or like this

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/object", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody TestObject create(@Validated @RequestBody TestObject obj, BindingResult result) {
```

Here, @Valid is [javax.validation.Valid](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/Valid.html), and @Validated is [org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/annotation/Validated.html). The docs for the latter say

> Variant of JSR-303's Valid, supporting the specification of validation
>   groups. Designed for convenient use with Spring's JSR-303 support but
>   not JSR-303 specific.

which doesn't help much because it doesn't tell exactly how it's different. If at all. Both seem to be working pretty fine for me.

Comment: Might be interesting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18911154/how-to-specify-validation-group-for-valid

Comment: _"supporting the specification of validation groups"_ is a very explicit statement.

Comment: I should think that Valid is tightly coupled with JSR 303 validations (NotNull, etc). Whereas you can create other validation/groups and have them checked in Validated.

Comment: @zeroflagL, true, but since I have never used it, I missed the point and fixated instead on the “not JSR-303 specific” part. Now it's clear.

Answer (score 120, accepted):

As you quoted from the documentation, `@Validated` was added to support "validation groups", i.e. group of fields in the validated bean. This can be used in multi step forms where you may validate name, email, etc.. in first step and then other fields in following step(s).

The reason why this wasn't added into `@Valid` annotation is because that it is standardized using the java community process (JSR-303), which takes time and Spring developers wanted to allow people to use this functionality sooner.

Go to [this jira ticket](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-6373) to see how the annotation came into existence.

Answer (score 206):

A more straight forward answer. 
For those who still don't know what on earth is ***"validation group"***.

**Usage for `@Valid` Validation**

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "createAccount")
public String stepOne(@Valid Account account) {...}
```

Form object:

```
public class Account {

    @NotBlank
    private String username;

    @Email
    @NotBlank
    private String email;

}
```

---

**Usage for `@Validated` Validation Group**
Source: http://blog.codeleak.pl/2014/08/validation-groups-in-spring-mvc.html

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "stepOne")
public String stepOne(@Validated(Account.ValidationStepOne.class) Account account) {...}

@RequestMapping(value = "stepTwo")
public String stepTwo(@Validated(Account.ValidationStepTwo.class) Account account) {...}
```

Form object:

```
public class Account {

    @NotBlank(groups = {ValidationStepOne.class})
    private String username;

    @Email(groups = {ValidationStepOne.class})
    @NotBlank(groups = {ValidationStepOne.class})
    private String email;

    @NotBlank(groups = {ValidationStepTwo.class})
    @StrongPassword(groups = {ValidationStepTwo.class})
    private String password;

    @NotBlank(groups = {ValidationStepTwo.class})
    private String confirmedPassword;

}
```

Comment: To keep in mind. \@Validated doesn't validate nested DTOs, you need to put \@Valid on those nested fields (Account#user for example) in order to propagate validation for them.

Comment: @Validated also can be used on classes to enable validation of @Min/@Max that reside next to method arguments of that class, which doesn't happen by default. public void update(@Min(10) Long count) {}

Answer (score 23):

In the example code snippets of the question, `@Valid` and `@Validated` make no difference. But if the `@RequestBody` is annotated with a `List` object, or is a string value annotated by `@RequestParam`, the validation will not take effect.

We can use the `@Validated`'s method-level validation capability to make it work. To achieve this, the key point is to place `@Validated` on the class. This may be another important difference between `@Valid` and `@Validated` in spring framework.

Refrence

- [Spring boot docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-validation.html)

Comment: Could you explain why the annotation has no effect for `List` objects? I assume that this will also not work for other collections like `Map`?

Maybe you could give me a more detailed explanation in my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60167961/cascaded-bean-validation-2-0-not-working-with-nested-object-inside-map

Comment: @Theiaz As you wish

Comment: What I was looking for!

Comment: This is actually a more important distinction than validation groups. No one uses validation groups.

Answer (score 12):

Just for simplifying:

> `@Validated` annotation is a class-level annotation that we can use to tell `Spring` to validate parameters that are passed into a method of the annotated class.

and

> `@Valid` annotation on method parameters and fields to tell `Spring` that we want a method parameter or field to be validated.

Answer (score 3):

besides above, you can only apply `@Valid` on a domain/field for nested validation, not with a `@validated`.

Answer (score 1):

`@Validated` at the class level of `@Controller`/`@RestController` is used to validate the `@PathVariable`/`@RequestParam` parameters

While `@Valid` won't work for `@PathVariable`/`@RequestParam` parameters

If validation fails for `@PathVariable`/`@RequestParam` it throws `ConstraintViolationException`

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-validate-requestparam-pathvariable

Answer (score -2):

`@Validated` can be used for a class:

```
@Validated
public class Person {
    @Size(min=3)
    private String name;
...
```