# Spring RequestBody optional validation

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a REST API controller like following code. If I use `@valid` annotation, every field of Client's entity are controlled for validation.

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = API.UPDATE_CLIENT, produces = ResponseType.JSON, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public HashMap update(
        @PathVariable(value = "id")int id,
        @RequestBody Client clientData
) {

    clientLogic.update(id, clientData);

    ....
}
```

Client's entity consists of about 5 fields (id, name, address, email, phone). When I update this records, I don't send all of 5 fields in RequestBody. I just want to validate coming from RequestBody.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You *could* use spring's `@Validated` instead and use `groups`. If I understand correctly, some values will be set, other won't. So, the *problem* is only with Null checks. You'd want to temporarly allow null values.

#### (1) Create an interface to be used as a *group*

```
public interface NullAllowed {}
```

#### (2) Assign the checks to the `NullAllowed` group

```
@Email(groups = NullAllowed.class) //email allows null, so you are good
private String email;

@NotNull //skip this check - not assigned to NullAllowed.class
@Size(min=1, groups = NullAllowed.class)
private String name;
```

#### (3) Use @Validated and specify the group to validate

```
public HashMap update(
    @PathVariable(value = "id")int id,
    @Validated(NullAllowed.class) @RequestBody Client clientData)
```

Only the checks marked with NullAllowed.class will be validated.

---

Check this out:

- JSR303 documentation on groups: http://beanvalidation.org/1.0/spec/#validationapi-validatorapi-groups
- [Difference between @Valid and @Validated in Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36173332/difference-between-valid-and-validated-in-spring)