# Using @BindingResult with @Validated

Tags: java, spring-boot, bean-validation, spring-validator

**Note:**
I read almost all stack post that i get when i search [@valid vs @validated](https://www.google.com/search?q=%40valid%20vs%20%40validated&rlz=1C1GCEA_enUS841US841&oq=%40Valid%20&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j0l2j69i61l3.4375j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&safe=active&ssui=on) and could not find answer so i am posting this.

I am so confused what `@Validated` is doing here. If `inputParms` is not valid, it is throwing `javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException` and not even going inside code. But if I replace `@Validated` with `@Valid` No exception thrown and `bindingResult.hasErrors()` is catching it.

```
@RestController
@Validated // what is this doing ??
public class MyRestController{
    @PostMapping(value="/my-data",produces= {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE})
    public ResponseEntity<?> doSomething(@Valid @RequestBody MyInputParam inputParms,BindingResult bindingResult){
        if(bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            //do something here
        }
    }
}
```

So if i use `@Validated`,  `BindingResult` is not useful at all ?
Or even simply how `@Validated` is different from `@Valid`

Answer (score 0):

See [Difference between @Valid and @Validated in Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36173332/difference-between-valid-and-validated-in-spring).

The problem in your particular case is that `@Validated` is mixed with `@Valid`. Options to fix this:

- remove the `@Validated` declared on the class and use either `@Validated` or `@Valid` for the parameter
- use either `@Valid` or `@Validated` in both places (class and parameter)

```java
@RestController
public class MyRestController {

    @PostMapping(value = "/my-data", produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE})
    public ResponseEntity<?> doSomething(@Validated @RequestBody MyInputParam inputParms, 
                                         BindingResult bindingResult) {
        if(bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            //do something here
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: The link that you mentioned is already on my question as i read that. The solution you are saying works but my question is if i use validated on class level and valid on method, what is throrwing `javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException`. I am sure i am missing somethig here.