# Issue with white space sent in the header of a HTTP request in spring-boot

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, http, request-headers

Working on an API which is allowing the empty spaces being sent from the `RequestHeader` of the request from POSTMAN which is not allowed but the request binding is successful and have tried with different ways of using and overriding methods in `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler`. Can someone please suggest the solution,Have used all the constarint validations such as `@Valid`,`@NotBlank`,`@NotEmpty`.

ControllerAdvice

```
 @ControllerAdvice
  public class DemoControllerAdvice extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler{

@Override
protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMethodArgumentNotValid(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex,
        HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return super.handleMethodArgumentNotValid(ex, headers, status, request);
}

@Override
protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleServletRequestBindingException(ServletRequestBindingException ex,
        HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
    System.out.println(ex.getMessage());

    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED).build();
}
}
```

Controller

```
@RestController
public class StudentResource {

@GetMapping(path="/testing")
public void method(@RequestBody Student student,@Valid 
 @RequestHeader(value="Authorization") @Size(min=1)  @NotBlank String auth) 
{

    System.out.println("Valid request");

}

}
```

[image: Image where the Authorization headers is Empty]

It should not be able to accept empty literal values like " " similar to the postman

Comment: While the duplicate question might not be exactly the same, in essence, it's the same problem. When using method argument vallidation, you should add the `@Validated` annotation to your controller.

Comment: @g00glen00b,It did not work and please let me know the difference between Valid  and Validated annotations

Comment: There's a Stack Overflow question about that as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36173332/difference-between-valid-and-validated-in-spring. I'll add it to the list of duplicates.