# Springboot javax validations are not working

Tags: java, spring-boot, validation, bean-validation

My springboot version is 2.3.7. I know that spring-boot-starter-validation is not a transitive dependency of spring-boot-starter-web. But even after adding it separately my annotations are not working.

//below dependency i have added in build.gradle
compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'

//sample class for which I want error when requested

```
 @Data
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @RequiredArgsConstructor(staticName = "of")
    public class UpdateRequest {
    
        @NotNull
        @NonNull
        private BigDecimal number;
    }
```

Here, lombok @NonNull is working but @NotNull is not. Nor other javax validators. What else is I am missing here?

Comment: check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61959918/spring-boot-validations-stopped-working-after-upgrade-from-2-2-5-to-2-3-0

Comment: and share the controller class you are using this class for.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are missing `@Valid` on the `UpdateRequest` parameter of your request handler method:

```java
@PostMapping("somepath")
public String update(@Valid UpdateRequest updateRequest, BindingResult bindingResult)
```