# spring-boot-starter-validation not found

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to use custom validators but they are never invoked. I've been trying to fix this problem for days now. I have looked online and people are saying that SPRING 2.3+ now needs spring-boot-starter-validation to be added to the pom. So I did, but I receive an [image: error message]

I dont understand why this is the issue and I haven't seen anyone have this problem so far. I've looked at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61959918/spring-boot-validations-stopped-working-after-upgrade-from-2-2-5-to-2-3-0), although the answer to that is something which the person already tried in their OP (confusing). Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried to `./mvnw clean package`?

Comment: Seems to be some kind of hiccup. Maybe restarting your IDE helps. The package definitely exists: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-validation/2.3.1.RELEASE

Comment: I did clean and it fixed it, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

./mvnw clean package – **answered by Turing85**

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue and here is how I got it fixed

1. run `./mvnw clean package` if you are using Windows You might need to use `mvnw.cmd clean package`
2. make sure the spring boot version you are using is the same as the starter validation version

   ```
   <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.17</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.17</version>
    </dependency>
   ```