# What might be the problem with Spring Boot Validation?

Tags: java, spring, database

I started a basic Spring Boot banking application. Basically, `POST` need mandatory fields for amount and user. I have added `@Valid` and `@NotEmpty`, but using these, empty `POST` goes through as well.

***clientController.java***

```
@RestController
public class clientController {

@Autowired
private clientRepo repo;

@PostMapping("/saveClient")
ResponseEntity<String> saveClient(@Valid @RequestBody Client client){
    repo.save(client);
    return ResponseEntity.ok("Client saved.");
}
@GetMapping("/payments")
List<Client> getAll(){
    return repo.findAll();
}
```

}

***Client.java***

```
@Entity
@Data
public class Client {
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private UUID id = UUID.randomUUID() ;

@DecimalMin("1.0")
private double amount;
@NotNull
private String debtorIban;

private LocalDateTime createdAt = LocalDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC).withNano(0);
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Boot - Validations stopped working after upgrade from 2.2.5 to 2.3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61959918/spring-boot-validations-stopped-working-after-upgrade-from-2-2-5-to-2-3-0)

Comment: Maybe? Before trying this, wrong inputs went through. Now nothing goes throug, I get Internal Server Error 500. I'm not sure if I have a problem somewhere with my code or there is some other problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem.
By changing double to BigDecimal, the validation goes through.