# Why is @Validated required for validating Spring controller request parameters?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, validation, spring-mvc

With the following validation setup in an annotated MVC controller:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users")
@Validated  // <-- without this, the @Size annotation in setPassword() has no effect
public class UserController {

    @PutMapping("/{id}/password")
    public void setPassword(@PathVariable long id, @RequestBody @Size(min = 8) String password) {
        /* ... */
    }

    @PutMapping("/{id}/other")
    public void setOther(@PathVariable long id, @RequestBody @Valid MyFormObject form) {
        /* ... */
    }
}
```

`@Validated` on the controller is required for the method parameter since it's not a "complex" object. In comparison, the `@Valid` annotation on the `setOther` method works without the `@Validated` annotation.

Why is `@Validated` required? Why not enable it by default? Is there a cost to its use?

#### edit

Note that [Difference between @Valid and @Validated in Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36173332/difference-between-valid-and-validated-in-spring) is related (I read it before asking this), but it doesn't address the *why* in my question.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Validation of objects is done by Hibernate Validator using the annotations from Jakarta Bean Validation 2.0. Something needs to trigger hibernate validator to run.

SpringMVC calls the controller methods when it sees a parameter with `@Valid` it will pass that object to hibernate validator. Hibernate validator will

1. Examine the class of the object to figure out what validation rules have been put on the class fields
2. Execute the validation rules against the fields marked up with validation annotations.

So in this case

```java
@PutMapping("/{id}/other")
public void setOther(@PathVariable long id, @RequestBody @Valid MyFormObject form) {
        /* ... */
}
```

`MyFormObject` has annotations on it  that the hibernate validator can find to validate the object.

In this case

```java
@PutMapping("/{id}/password")
public void setPassword(@PathVariable long id, @RequestBody @Size(min = 8) String password) {
        /* ... */
}
```

java.lang.String does not have any annotations defined on it for hibernate validator to discover.

`@Valid` comes from the Bean validation package `javax.validation.Valid` while `@Validated` comes from Spring `org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated`

`@Validated` annotation activates the Spring Validation AOP interceptor and it will examine method parameters to see if they have any validation annotations on them, if they do then Spring will call hibernate validator with each specific annotation for example `@Size(min = 8) String password` means call hibernate size validator and pass the value of the parameter password in this case hibernate validator does not need to scan `java.lang.String` to see if it has validation annotations on it. `@Validated` works on any spring `@Component` you can use it on `@Service` classes for example.

There is extra overhead for using `@Validated` similar to using `@Transactional` so that is why you have to opt into it. In the case of `javax.validation.Valid` Spring MVC needs to check the annotations on the controller method parameters so when it sees `@Valid` it is easy for it to send that object the Hibernate Validator without needing to add an AOP interceptor.

Comment: What I don't get is that, without `@Validated`, some code in Spring inspects the parameters for `@Valid` annotations on parameters and run the annotated ones through the validator. How is that so different from looking for annotations such as `@Size` (i.e. those annotated with `@Constraint`) and running them through the validator? Why can't the interceptor that handles `@Valid` handle both cases?

Comment: The interceptor work with all spring components and is not part of spring mvc. Spring MVC on it's own looks for the @Valid annotations