# Custom Validator for a class with Spring

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

So. I'm trying to have a custom validator for my method. This one:

```
    @PostMapping("/person")
    public Person create(@Validated(value = IPersonValidator.class) @RequestBody Person person, Errors errors) {
        LOGGER.info("Creating a person with the following fields: ");
        LOGGER.info(person.toString());

        if (errors.hasErrors()) {
            LOGGER.info("ERROR. Error creating the person!!");
            return null;
        }

        //return personService.create(person);
        return null;
    }
```

This is my Validator class:

```
@Component
public class PersonValidator implements Validator, IPersonValidator {

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
        return Person.class.equals(clazz);
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
        Person person = (Person) target;
        if (person.getName() == null || person.getName().trim().isEmpty()) {
            errors.reject("name.empty", "null or empty");
        }
    }
}
```

And my interface:

```
public interface IPersonValidator {
}
```

And my class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "persons")
@Data
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "person_sequence")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "person_sequence", sequenceName = "person_sequence", allocationSize = 1)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;
    //@NotBlank(message = "Name cannot be null or empty")
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @NotBlank(message = "Lastname cannot be null or empty")
    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;
    @Column(name = "last_name_2")
    private String lastName2;

    public Person(String name, String lastName, String lastName2) {
        this.name = name;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.lastName2 = lastName2;
    }
}
```

What am I expecting is for it to enter the validate method since Im using the annotation (@Validate) with the class that I want. I tried it too using the @Valid annotation, but it still won't enter in my custom validate method.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This code `@Validated(value = IPersonValidator.class)` is use for "grouping" of validations. Yoy say to validator valid only these constrains with `groups = {IPersonValidator.class}`.

For better understanding of custom validators see: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-custom-validator

edit:

This code `@Validated(value = IPersonValidator.class)` doesn't use your validator. From @Validated documantation:

> value() specify one or more validation groups to apply to the
> validation step kicked off by this annotation.

Validation groups are use for turning on/off of some valdations for some fields in data class. Se more here: https://www.baeldung.com/javax-validation-groups

For creating you own custom valdation you must create custom constrain annotation and custom validator for this annotation. This custom constrain annotation you may use on some field in data class. I really strong recommend read this https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-custom-validator

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit please? I don't think I understand it

Comment: @Axvemi In edit.

Comment: So do I need to add a validator to each field? Can't I have a class Validator?

Comment: You may have class validator but you must validate this class as field in another class.

Comment: Ended up fixing it with this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71768778/how-to-use-custom-validators-in-spring

Stopped just before where the service layer explanation starts