# Spring Boot Bean Validation In HashMap Not Working

Tags: spring, spring-boot, bean-validation

I am creating a REST controller which shall take a list of Dtos.
It all works but the validation is not working, therefore it fails during persistence only.

My code:

```java
@Valid @RequestBody HashMap<String, MyDto> myDtoMap
```

And unfortunately the MyDto does not get validated.

I also tried this way:

```java
@Valid @RequestBody HashMap<String, @Valid MyDto> myDtoMap
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try :

annotate your controller with :

```
@RestController
@Validated
```

Then you can validate you class with :

```
@RequestBody HashMap<String, @Valid MyDto> myDtoMap
```

Comment: Thank you. You were right with `@Validated`. Do you know why it is necessary? I think `@Valid` should be enough?

Comment: Here is a good answer to your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57696133/8093726