# Spring boot - How to validate Multipartfile in rest application

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest

I want to validate extension of Multipartfile object. I added @Valid and my custon annotation to parameter `@ImageFileValid` but it doesn't work.

```
@PutMapping("/{id}")
ProductDto updateProduct(@RequestPart @Valid ProductDto product, @PathVariable Long id,@RequestPart @Valid @ImageFileValid MultipartFile image) {
    return productMapper.productToProductDto(productService.update(productMapper.productDtoToProduct(product),id));
}
```

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-valid-vs-validated !?

Comment: @xerx593 This is not question about difference between valid and validation

Comment: the question not...but maybe the answer!? ;)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57696133/592355

Comment: Can you please share ImageFileValid validation ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very short but clear reference from [Spring-Boot, Validation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/io.html#io.validation):

> The method validation feature supported by Bean Validation 1.1 is automatically enabled as long as a JSR-303 implementation (such as Hibernate validator) is on the classpath. This lets bean methods be annotated with `javax.validation` constraints on their parameters and/or on their return value. **Target classes** with such annotated **methods need** to be annotated with the **`@Validated` annotation** at the **type level** for their methods to be searched for inline constraint annotations.

So, please annotate (the containing) **controller** class with `@Validated` & report if any issues.

---

A [sample repo at github](https://github.com/xerx593/soq70225979).

Comment: Hi @xerx593 , i'm using Spring boot 2.7 and i can't get to work. Do you have any idea please? I'm sending the multipart file with a json using mixed content-type.

Comment: ..the easier in this scenario, @Jedupont: We want (he wanted) to validate the json "inside", [in our new scenario](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76122829/592355), we want to validate the content type(/length/"file name"...) of a *(multi)"part"* which can/should be json...