# Spring: validation with @RequestPart isn't working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

If I send a PNG file, the file name is returned with a HTTP 200 code. While only a PDF file should be accepted :

```java
@PutMapping(consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<String> send(
    @PathVariable Integer id,
    @Valid @FileContentType(contentTypes = {
      MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF_VALUE
    }) @RequestPart("custom_file") MultipartFile file
) {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(file.getOriginalFilename(), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Note that my validator works when I use it on @RequestBody...

I tried to log my validator to see if it is triggered or not, but I don't even get in.

**EDIT 1 (partial solution) :**

`@Valid` seems to work only for complex objects. It doesn't work on @RequestParam/Part directly cause there is no binding. The easiest way is to create a class that englobe the multipart file and where there is the validation logic.

**However, this does not apply to my case, because in reality I want it to work with mixed content. I send both a json body and a multipart file.**

So I can't put all my validation in the same class.

Comment: Please also test it in "real container" (not only mock environment) .. experiment!) Iin "full" (servlet) environment it will behave differently/better! To test against "full" context: replace all "mockMvc", with "(test)restTemplate/webclient/any other http client(tech)"  preserving `@SpringBootTest` ... see https://spring.io/guides/gs/testing-web/ + below links

Comment: I don't have tests in my current production environment :/ I am using `@RestController` since it is a Restful API and it works for now. I just don't get proper exception handling, I will look!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update:

> ..  I would like to be able to apply validation annotations on my json properties

Yes, we can also do that, but cannot use the "ValidMediaType" annotation on `SomeDto` (as a root):

```
// ...
@PutMapping(value = "/pdf/json/v2", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
  public ResponseEntity<String> pdf2Controller(
      @Valid @RequestPart SomeDto someJson,
      @Valid @ValidMediaType(MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF_VALUE) @RequestPart MultipartFile someFile) throws IOException {
    System.err.println(someJson);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(someFile.getOriginalFilename(), HttpStatus.OK);
  }
}

@lombok.Value(staticConstructor = "of")
class SomeDto {
  @NotNull
  String foo;
  @Size(min = 3, max = 6)
  String bar;
}
```

And Tests ... :

```
@Test
void testPdfJson2Valid() throws Exception {
  final MockPart jsonPart = new MockPart("someJson", "test.json",
      testValidJson.getInputStream().readAllBytes());
  // we need this! (so implicitely validate, but other error code)
  jsonPart.getHeaders().setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
  mockMvc.perform(putMultipart("/validated/pdf/json/v2")
      .file(mockPdf)
      .part(jsonPart)) // !
      .andExpectAll(status().isOk(), // !!
          content().string("aha.pdf"));
}

@Test
void testPdfJson2ValidAlt() throws Exception {
  mockMvc.perform(
      putMultipart("/validated/pdf/json/v2")
          .file(mockPdf)
          // also
          .file(validJsonFile()))
      .andExpectAll(status().isOk(), // ..works !!
          content().string("aha.pdf"));
}

@Test
void testPdfJson2unsupportedMediaType() throws Exception {
  MockPart jsonPart = new MockPart("someJson", "test.json", testValidJson.getInputStream().readAllBytes());
  mockMvc.perform(
      putMultipart("/validated/pdf/json/v2")
          .file(mockPdf)
          .part(jsonPart)) // no/wrong content type
      .andExpect(status().isUnsupportedMediaType()); // !
}

@Test
void testPdfJson2Invalid() throws Exception {
  MockPart jsonPart = new MockPart("someJson", "test.json", testInvalidJson.getInputStream().readAllBytes());
  jsonPart.getHeaders().setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
  mockMvc.perform(
      putMultipart("/validated/pdf/json/v2")
          .file(mockPdf)
          .part(jsonPart))
      .andExpect(status().isBadRequest()); // !
}
```

[all here](https://github.com/xerx593/soq70225979)

Original:

---

I updated my [old repository](https://github.com/xerx593/soq70225979) with your new controller:

```java
@PutMapping(value = "/pdf/{id}", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<String> pdfController(
    @PathVariable Integer id,
    @Valid @ValidMediaType(MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF_VALUE) @RequestPart("custom_file") MultipartFile file) {
  // just a test/demo:
  return new ResponseEntity<>(file.getOriginalFilename(), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

..and Tests:

```java
@Test
void testPdfInvalid() throws Exception {
  mockMvc.perform(
      putMultipart("/validated/pdf/1")
          .file(new MockMultipartFile(
              "custom_file",
              "ohoh.jpg",
              MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE, // ??
              (byte[]) null)))
      .andExpect(status().isBadRequest()) // !!
      .andExpect(content().string(endsWith("application/pdf.\"}")));
}

@Test
void testPdfValid() throws Exception {
  mockMvc.perform(
      putMultipart("/validated/pdf/1")
          .file(new MockMultipartFile(
              "custom_file",
              "aha.pdf",
              MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF_VALUE, // !
              (byte[]) null)))
      .andExpectAll(status().isOk(), // !!
          content().string("aha.pdf")); /// !!!
}
```

...works like charm.

---

Here is, how I could handle the multipart file + json parts scenario:

Updated controller:

```java
// 1.
import javax.servlet.http.Part;
// - it has built-in handling (as method argument by spring-web(flux))
// - it has "content-type" attribute (to validate)
// - and it has input stream (to read json) 
// ...

// normally we would get "json objects" in controller, now due to validation, we have to read it from the Part
@Autowired ObjectMapper objectMapper;

@PutMapping(value = "/pdf/json", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<String> pdf1Controller(
    @Valid @ValidMediaType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE) @RequestPart Part someJson,
    @Valid @ValidMediaType(MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF_VALUE) @RequestPart MultipartFile someFile) throws IOException {
  System.err.println(
    objectMapper.readValue(someJson.getInputStream(), SomeDto.class)
  );
  return new ResponseEntity<>(someFile.getOriginalFilename(), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

We need to extend/an additional Validator (which is capable of `Part` and our "custom annotation"):

```java
class MultiPartPartValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ValidMediaType, Part> { // ... analogous to existing
```

We need to mention/enable/wire it on our annotation:

```java
@Constraint(validatedBy = {MultiPartPartValidator.class // , ...
```

The tests (hardest part:) can look like this:

```java
@Test
void testPdfJsonValid() throws Exception {
  MockPart jsonPart = new MockPart("someJson", "test.json", testJson.getInputStream().readAllBytes());
  jsonPart.getHeaders().setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
  mockMvc.perform(
      putMultipart("/validated/pdf/json")
          .file(mockPdf)
          .part(jsonPart)) // !
      .andExpectAll(status().isOk(), // !!
          content().string("aha.pdf"));
}

@Test
void testPdfJsonInvalid() throws Exception {
  mockMvc.perform(
      putMultipart("/validated/pdf/json")
          .file(mockPdf)
          .part(new MockPart("someJson", "test.json", testJson.getInputStream().readAllBytes()))) // ??
      .andExpect(status().isBadRequest()); // !
}
```

Looks also good in postman:

[image: postman screenshot]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the problem is that in this way, will doing `objectMapper.readValue(...)` control the validation annotations for each property in my DTO ? I would like to be able to apply validation annotations on my json properties.

Comment: no, that's the point: or you have "exact" content type validation, or you have (implicit! content type,,,but still very flexible), and have the "json validation" .. i will try that ;)

Comment: Ok I'm not sure I understand then. I'll have to look into it. In itself, it's not a big deal that it's implicit, but how can I validate with the annotations that the X property of my json with `@NotNull`, `@Min(3)`, `@Max(7)` ?

Comment: Thank you !!! It's a pleasure to see people like you who take their time to help others! However, I see that it is mandatory `@Validated` at the top of the controller.  As a result, my last problem is that the exception thrown is `ConstraintViolationException` rather than `MethodArgumentNotValidException` or `BindException` which I already handle via an @ControllerAdvice to format the errors for my API Rest. Is there a simple way to handle this without rewriting an @ExceptionHandler for this particular case?

Comment: .. exception handling is tricky, esp. In "mock mvc" environment ... for the very reason :) ... [See here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-petclinic/pull/1236)(e.a.)..

Comment: When we omit our [handler](https://github.com/xerx593/soq70225979/blob/main/src/main/java/com/stackoverflow/web/ExceptionHandlers.java), tests will fail... (with exact symptoms:);(;( I was very lucky to get it working -2y ago !:)

Comment: Exactly, I need a handler because I would have liked to have the validation errors formatted in json with the concerned field rather than having a `ConstraintViolationException` thrown. I'm already doing this with `MethodArgumentNotValidException`. I'll see what I can do then, thanks! But it seems more complicated to get the field in error from this exception.
In the meantime, I accept your answer since it answers the main problem rather well.