# Spring boot rest api, fail on unknown property in the body request

Tags: spring-boot, objectmapper

I have a spring-boot rest api service.
**Just for one of the rest POST api calls** I would like to make sure that no additional properties are send in the request body object. I have realised there is a way to use a custom `objectMapper` that will fail deserialisation in this kind of case but I have a bit of problem setting up an object mapper just for the particular call. What would be the best approach, pls write/extend my example.

My example:

```
PostMapping("/")
public static ResponseEntity apiCallNeedsToFailInCaseOfAdditionalPropertiesInBody(@RequestBody body){
/// some code
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, if you are trying to hit API via Postman, it will automatically give you a result with error message saying `"Additional parameters/properties found"` or something similar in error response when you passed additional parameter(s).

**Your solution will also work, but no need for the same.**

Instead, when you have endpoints growing in your application, you can make use of `@Valid and @Validated` annotations to take care of that request body parameter validations.

Check if this article throws some light around your query

[Difference between @Valid and @Validated in Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36173332/difference-between-valid-and-validated-in-spring)

Comment: First thanks for your answer. API is not returning a response "Additional parameters/properties found", request are executed with no problem and additional body params are not taken in to consideration at all. Now validation comes after the request is deseriliased so I think this is not useful for me.