# Bean validation: method constraints and groups

Tags: bean-validation, java-ee-7

I use Java EE7 with Bean validations.

I have session bean with a method, where I have defined validation constraints.

```
public void doTest(@NotNull @Valid Media param1) {
  // do something
}
```

Class `Media`has defined some constraint with groups. Is it possible to validate call of method `doTest`only for specific groups?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found solution with standard annotations. It uses `@ConvertGroup`.

Working example is:

```
public void doTest(
        @NotNull @Valid 
        @ConvertGroup(from = Default.class, to = TestGroup.class) 
        Media param1) {

    // do something
}
```

`TestGroup` is defined on some constraints inside `Media` class.

Answer (score 0):

The standard java @Valid annotation can not validate groups. But spring has @Validated that can do. Have a look on this answer.
[How to specify validation group for @Valid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18911154/how-to-specify-validation-group-for-valid).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I don't use Spring. Finally I found solution by myself using `@ConvertGroup` annotation.